# put odd and even values into groups with custom key

Tags: groovy

Let's say I've got a list of numbers:

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to separate it into two groups - `odd` and `even` numbers.

I am doing it like this:

```
def map = list.groupBy { it % 2 == 1 }
```

The resulting `map` looks like this

```
[true:[1, 3, 5], false:[2, 4, 6]]
```

But how to set my custom key for `odd` and `even` values instead of having `true` and `false`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ]
def map = list.groupBy { it % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even' }
```

Comment: Shorter: `list.groupBy { it % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even' }` ;-)